# Cannot read simple binary integers from file? (C++)

Tags: c++, binary, ifstream, integer

My code is simply as this:

**UPDATED**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ifstream r("foo.bin", ios::binary);
  ofstream w("foo.bin", ios::binary);
  int i;

  int ints[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9};
  w.write((char*)&ints, sizeof(ints));

  int in_ints[10];
  r.read((char*)&in_ints, sizeof(in_ints));

  for(i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
    cout << in_ints[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Now, the write portion appears to be successful, for example running the od command with 32 bit longs (my system is 32 bit) will display the correct sequence, including a hex dump.

Reading however, I get random sequences such and negative integers that should not happen (it is split up, and mostly zeros as my integers are small, the sign bits should not be on.)

Do you see why my read method has failed to work, when it is really an opposite of my write method?

Comment: please post a complete piece of code.

Comment: Is this your actual code? If so, you might want to try closing or at least flushing the writing stream before using the reading stream.

Comment: I apologize, I have posted the whole code. Let me try flushing the stream.

Comment: Ah, my lack of C++ knowledge in its entirety.. If you could post this as a response Sven, I could accept it. It works.

Comment: You don't know whether the call to `read` succeeded. Always check return values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `w.flush()` or `w.close()` before `r.read`. the problem is when you write it usually bufferes text and doesn't save it in file. so there is nothing realy in file for `r.read`.

Answer (score 6):

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    {
        ofstream w( "foo.txt" );
        int ints[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9};
        w.write((char*)&ints, sizeof(ints));
    }
    {
        ifstream r( "foo.txt" );
        int in_ints[10];
        r.read((char*)&in_ints, sizeof(in_ints));
        for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            cout << in_ints[i] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 0

Note there are some numbers missing from your initialisation.

Comment: Yep, `+1` from me. Define your variables as late as possible (think of YAGNI), and as local as possible.

Comment: A nice example actually, I've tried to see use for scope operators in C++, and maybe this could be a way. I wonder if relying on out of scope to call the deconstructor is a good way however, as I may change it later and forget to add the .close().

Answer (score 1):

Data written to a file isn't necessarily visible to other streams (in
the same process or not) until the file is closed, or at least flushed.
And if the file `"foo.bin"` doesn't exist before you start the program,
opening it for reading will fail (and so all further use will be a
no-op).  Your program violates one of the most basic rules of
programming: if anything can fail, always check that it hasn't before
continuing.  You don't check any of the results of your IO.

I might also add that reading and writing data this way is very, very
fragile, and can generally only be guaranteed to work within the same
process—even recompiling with a different version of the compiler
or different compiler options may cause the data representation to 
change, with the results that you won't be able to read data written
earlier.  In the case of arrays of `int`, of course, this is highly
unlikely as long as you don't change machine architectures.  But in
general, if you'll need to reread the data in the future, it's a
technique best avoided.  (The `(char*)` are `reinterpret_cast`, and as
we know, `reinterpret_cast` is a very strong signal that there is a
portability issue.)